# Does $\sum\limits _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\pi \left(-3\right)^{n+1}}{7^n}$ converge/diverge.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

Does $$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\pi \left(-3\right)^{n+1}}{7^n}$$ converge/diverge.

If it converges, state the sum.

I rewrote this series as follows:

$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\pi \left(-3\right)^{n+1}}{7^n}$$

$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\pi \left(-3\right)^{n+1}}{7^n}=\pi \sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(-3\right)^{n+1}}{7^n} = \pi \sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(-3\right)^{n}(-3)}{7^n} = (-3\pi) \sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:(\frac{-3}{7})^n$$

Here we see the geometric series into play, in the form $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }ar^n$, where $r$ = $\dfrac{-3}{7}$, and we know that if $|r| < 1$, then the series converges to $\dfrac{a}{1-r}$.

$a$ is first non-zero term, so we have $a = -3\pi (\dfrac{-3}{7})^3 = \dfrac{81\pi}{343}$

$\therefore$ the series converges to $\dfrac{\dfrac{81\pi}{343}}{1+\dfrac{3}{7}} \approx 0.52$

I think this is right, but I verified with Wolfram alpha, and it got different solutions. Who is correct?

[image]

Comment: By the usual [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), it clearly converges.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen This seems unnecessary - it's obviously a geometric series, which actually provides the value of the sum too.

Comment: Do you know what you put into Wolfram Alpha? I (and I think others) am incapable of recreating what you got, but I'm definitely interested in what may have caused it.

Comment: I have found the cause. When entering pi(-3), instead of pi*(-3), it assumes that the pi you're talking about is the pi function, where pi(z) is the number of primes less than or equal to z. Since there are no prime numbers less than -3 (prime numbers must be positive), pi(-3) = 0, so the sum equals 0.

I still have no idea why it's considered a divergent series, when it is equivalently 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how you wrote it in WA, but this is the answer I'm getting: (I included my query for reference)

[image: Excerpt from Wolframalpha]

Comment: Just verified myself, using the mathematica notation `Sum[ pi*(-3)^(n+1) / 7^n, {n, 3, Infinity}]` (sometimes wolfram alpha likes MMA notation more)

Comment: That's really weird how WA accepts different notations, shows the same equation in their graphics, but comes up with different results, anyways thanks